# .htaccess странные редиректы на поддоменах

Tags: .htaccess

Имеется свой стандартный .htaccess которому уже года и года. На всех хостингах его использую и никогда проблем не было. Недавно стал переезжать на VPS и возникли трудности.

При работе с поддоменами (`sub.domain.com`) происходит множество редиректов и сервер выбивает "Internal Server Error". Причем при работе с самим `domain.com` проблем нет.

Админы хостинга говорят проблема в .htaccess, а я с этой темой плохо дружу, к сожалению. Подскажите, что в нем не так?

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
php_flag register_globals Off
php_flag session.use_cookies on
php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
php_value default_charset "utf-8"


Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(images/|uploads/|js/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_/\-%\ ]*)/$ /$1/index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_/\-%\ ]+)/{0}$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_/\-%\ ]+)/{0}\.(html|php|js|xml|txt)$ index.php?mods=$1&ext=$2 [L,QSA]


ErrorDocument 404 /page_not_found.html
```

Лог:

```
[error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Вся суть последних реврайтов сводится к отправке запроса на index.php такого вида:
http://sub.domain.com/some/module/request.html?someget=test
$_GET:

```
array(3) {
  ["mods"]=>
  string(19) "some/module/request"
  ["ext"]=>
  string(4) "html"
  ["someget"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

http://sub.domain.com/some/module/request/
$_GET:

```
array(2) {
  ["mods"]=>
  string(25) "some/module/request/index"
  ["ext"]=>
  string(4) "html"
}
```

Comment: Что в логе ошибок веб сервера?

Comment: Смотрите еще какая версия apache и php

Comment: Добавил в вопрос лог сервера. Php и apache аналогичны.

Comment: Странно, как на других доменах это работает. Последний `RewriteRule` зациклен сам на себя. Эти `/{0}` подстроки смысла не имеют.

Comment: @visman Помогите пожалуйста его подправить, буду вам признателен. С регулярками проблемы и htaccess =( 
Я в тело вопроса показал пример как он работает на других серверах.